# Handle a login dialoge box in UFT

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I'm automating a web application but I'm being block by an authentication login pop-up on chrome.
Is there a way to handle login popup in Chrome?

[image]

Here's the pop-up authentication I'm encountering.

Although I have captured the pop-up in Edge Browser via UI Automation add-in, it seems that it is not working in chrome.

It is much appreciated if someone can share a workaround or a solution.

I'm using UFT One 2021 version.

Comment: You don't need to handle it - you skip it - you can pass credentials in the url by doing `http://username:password@www.yoursitegoeshere.com`

Comment: @RichEdwards but what if he has test goals to pursue in the logon dialog/logon process?

Comment: Hint: If you look at the "Known limitations" section of the UFT documentation, you will find that those dialogs are known to be not discoverable as Web dialogs, and there is a recommendation to use certain alternative identification techniques, alternative to Web.